# Nothing is appearing on the Desktop in Kali Linux

Tags: desktop, kali-linux, desktop-icons

I downloaded VMware workstation in Kali Linux. It wasn't running, it was having some header files issues. So I looked up the solution and someone said to run the following commands.

```
apt clean && apt update && apt dist-upgrade
```

After this, when I restarted the computer, all the icons from the desktop were removed.

[image: It's all blank]

The data is still there in the Home/username/Desktop directory.

[image]

Also there are only a few options when I right click the desktop.

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe you can check this QA in UNIX/Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/399627#399627

Comment: Please read: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No desktop icons in kali linux, but files can be seen on file explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1358618/no-desktop-icons-in-kali-linux-but-files-can-be-seen-on-file-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Kali linux, but I got it fixed using the Tweak tool.

> Tweak -> Extensions -> On the upper bar there is a switch.

This got disabled in my case for unknown reasons and I could not see the Desktop files or any kind of menu/icons at the Desktop.

Just enabling this switch *back on* fixed the problem.
I don't know if somehow a command can be run from the terminal to enable this switch, so maybe someone who knows can add this, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a dist-upgrade of my kali vm, and found the same issue. It appears to be due to the Gnome team deciding to get rid of desktop icons.

You can get them back using gnome extensions like https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1444/desktop-icons-enhanced/ but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is true - as of v30+ Gnome removed desktop icons in favor of extensions or other means to access or surface your frequently used apps/programs.

Comment: Please don’t post a new answer just to say that another answer is right.