# No desktop icons in kali linux, but files can be seen on file explorer

Tags: linux, desktop, kali-linux

In addition to that, I cant move a file or folder onto the desktop. It just does an animation that brings it back to the file explorer.

Also I have lost some options when right clicking on the desktop. There's supposed to be an Open in terminal option but the only thing I get is this

[image: The options I get when right clicking on the desktop]

This issue occurred when I did `apt-get dist-upgrade` and some other `apt-get` commands. My GNOME version is 33.0 if that is necessary.

Comment: The same "issue"? [Nothing is appearing on the Desktop in Kali Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1358244/432690)

Comment: Yes @KamilMaciorowski. But I have learned that it was not an issue with Kali, but with GNOME update. Here's the link https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=4983. Will just wait until they'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome 3.28 removes the option to display desktop icons
You have GNOME version 3.30 and it's weird that you still have problem.

Try this extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1444/desktop-icons-enhanced/

or this:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/

Comment: just wait for the September 30 release

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in 3.30.1

I just updated mine and they came back

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
then apt autoremove if you want to clean
Rebooted and icons were back
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with desktop icons, as you mentioned in you comment. However, be aware that many distros using the latest version of Gnome disable moving files and folders to the Desktop. This "feature" can be disabled by tweaking Gnome settings.

Personally, I find it very strange that a distro/Gnome would set this as the default. People have been using their Desktop to store files and folders for over 3 decades now. Why do they think k this change is necessary and mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

noticed this as well (Gnome version 3.30.0)
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/gnome-desktop-icons-removed-3-28

So, either bypass with extensions, or adapt to the new changes.